# Multi input & multi column for each loop PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables, foreach

Currently taking all get request through foreach function. Looking if column called season contains them. Next step is adding 1 more column to check if any get request is LIKE any of the next column values. The second column has to be an AND and not and OR, which means if the first column season contains any of the get requests AND the second column contains any of the GET requests.

Currently:

```
$array_name = array();
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $array_name[] = "'%" . escape_string($value) . "%'";
};

$string = implode(' OR season LIKE ', $array_name);

$tank = "SELECT * FROM shrubs2 WHERE season LIKE {$string}";
echo $tank;
```

First edit:

```
      function searchByColumn($values, $columnName) {
      $string = implode(" OR $columnName LIKE ", $values);
      return "SELECT * FROM shrubs2 WHERE $columnName LIKE $string";
  }

  $array_name = array();
  foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
      $array_name[] = "'%".escape_string($value)."%'";
  }

  $colNames = array("season", "日照"); // can add here more column names
  foreach($colNames as $colName) {
      $str = searchByColumn($array_name, $colName);
  }

  echo $str;


 ///// creating the query with the variable $str
```

Comment: hi and welcome to SO. it is unclear what your question is? Please read [ask]

Comment: Added some more context, hope this helps

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define **function** to search for each column:

```
function searchByColumn($values, $columnName) {
    $string = implode(" OR $columnName LIKE ", $values);
    return "SELECT * FROM shrubs2 WHERE $columnName LIKE $string";
}
```

Then use it as:

```
$array_name = array();
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $array_name[] = "'%".escape_string($value)."%'";
}

$colNames = array("season"); // can add here more column names
foreach($colNames as $colName) {
    $str = searchByColumn($array_name, $colName);
    echo $str; // or run it
}
```

Comment: I've edited my code, so you can see if I'm doing something wrong, currenly it only loops through the 2. value in the colNames array

Comment: query I get is SELECT * FROM shrubs2 WHERE 日照 LIKE '%夏%' OR 日照 LIKE '%秋%' OR 日照 LIKE '%半日陰%'

Comment: @dddddddooooosss - Notice you `echo` the `$str` outside the `foreach` loop - you need to echo / run it inside the loop. Did my post solve your problem?